# Google Cloud Platform: Not able to access the node files over internet

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform

I have a VM instance, in which I am running my node.js server and client on port 8081 and 8082. When I try to access my page through the [external ip]:8081 it times out. I have also added the firewall rule to allow all connections of all protocols on all ports. What could be the issue?

NOTE: I am using the standard node.js setup not the one that comes with Google Cloud Platform.

Comment: Does your application is running ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I turned off the Windows Firewall I was able to access the server from the internet.